# Override system headers include when compiling with gcc

Tags: c++, osx-mountain-lion

I'm currently trying to compile a C++ source file which use openssl headers, but the compiler uses system openssl headers located in /usr/include/openssl and I would like it uses the /usr/local/openssl/1.0.1c/include/openssl include path. I might have to give the "-I" flag pointing to the last path but it keeps the system one.

```
g++ -o src/base64.o -c -O3 -arch x86_64 -Iinclude/cryptoplus -I/usr/local/openssl/1.0.1c/include/openssl src/base64.cpp
```

My environment variables seem to not force using the /usr/include/openssl include dir and I'm working on OSX 10.8, sorry if it's novice question but it's kind disturbing.

In advance, thank you!

Comment: maybe it's because by default compiler is looking for headers in   /usr/include/ and subdirectories, using flag  -I you only say it that it might have used another path as well.  Try to point direct path to the header you need in your C++ source file, like #include </usr/local/openssl/1.0.1c/include/openssl/name_of_file.h> - also it's not good way

Comment: I thought `-I` specified paths were supposed to have priority over system include paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I was very tired ! The openssl include path wasn't right, I needed to specify

```
-I/usr/local/openssl/1.0.1c/include
```

without the openssl folder.

The include calls the header file inside the openssl folder

```
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
```

Thanks for your comments.